# How to add timeout to Deferred from Twisted's deferToThread API?

Tags: python, twisted

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import threads
from twisted.internet import defer
import time

def worker(arg):
    print 'Hello world'
     time.sleep(10)
    return 1

def run():
    print 'Starting workers'
    l = []
    for x in range(2):
        l.append(threads.deferToThread(worker, x))
    return defer.DeferredList(l)

def res(results):
    print results
    reactor.stop()

d = run()
d.addCallback(res)
reactor.run()
```

How to stop workers by timeout ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Threads cannot be interrupted unless they cooperate with you.  `time.sleep(10)` is not going to cooperate, so I don't think you can interrupt this worker.  If you have another kind of worker that has several discrete phases, or operates in a loop over some tasks, then you can do something like this:

```
def worker(stop, jobs):
    for j in jobs:
        if stop:
            break
        j.do()

stop = []
d = deferToThread(worker)

# This will make the list eval to true and break out of the loop.
stop.append(None)
```

This isn't Twisted specific, either.  This is just how threads work in Python.

Comment: As of 2019, this response should no longer be the accepted answer as there is a twisted call specifically made for this use case. 

https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.html#addTimeout

Comment: Not so.  Deferreds can have a timeout added but threads still cannot be interrupted without cooperation.

Comment: The title is unambiguous: "How to add timeout to twisted defer". The original user may have been confused about the cooperative nature of threads, but that's kind of aside the point. Right now, that specific search yields this SO answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Fixed the title for you

Answer (score 3):

While it may not be possible to interrupt the threads, the Deferred can be stopped via the `cancel` function, which I think is available in Twisted 10.1.0 and later.

I've used the following class to make Deferreds that callback a particular function if the Deferred hasn't fired after some time. It might be useful for someone that has the same question as that posed in the subject of the OP.

EDIT: As suggested by the comments below, it's best not to inherit from `defer.Deferred`. Therefore, I've changed the code to use a wrapper that achieves the same effect.

```
class DeferredWrapperWithTimeout(object):
    '''
    Holds a deferred that allows a specified function to be called-back
    if the deferred does not fire before some specified timeout.
    '''
    def __init__(self, canceller=None):
        self._def = defer.Deferred(canceller)

    def _finish(self, r, t):
        '''
        Function to be called (internally) after the Deferred
        has fired, in order to cancel the timeout.
        '''
        if ( (t!=None) and (t.active()) ):
            t.cancel()
        return r

    def getDeferred(self):
        return self._def

    def addTimeoutCallback(self, reactr, timeout,
                           callUponTimeout, *args, **kw):
        '''
        The function 'callUponTimeout' (with optional args or keywords)
        will be called after 'timeout' seconds, unless the Deferred fires.
        '''

        def timeoutCallback():
            self._def.cancel()
            callUponTimeout(*args, **kw)
        toc = reactr.callLater(timeout, timeoutCallback)
        return self._def.addCallback(self._finish, toc)
```

**Example** callback before timeout:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor

from DeferredWithTimeout import *

dw = DeferredWrapperWithTimeout()
d  = dw.getDeferred()

def testCallback(x=None):
    print "called"

def testTimeout(x=None):
    print "timedout"

d.addCallback(testCallback)
dw.addTimeoutCallback(reactor, 20, testTimeout, "to")
reactor.callLater(2, d.callback, "cb")
reactor.run()
```

Prints "called" and nothing else.

**Example** timeout before callback:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor

from DeferredWithTimeout import *

dw = DeferredWrapperWithTimeout()
d  = dw.getDeferred()

def testCallback(x=None):
    print "called"

def testTimeout(x=None):
    print "timedout"

d.addCallback(testCallback)
dw.addTimeoutCallback(reactor, 20, testTimeout, "to")
reactor.run()
```

Prints "timedout" after 20 seconds, and nothing else.

Comment: You really shouldn't subclass `Deferred`.  Implement this functionality as a separate helper, not a subclass.  http://pyvideo.org/video/1684/the-end-of-object-inheritance-the-beginning-of

Comment: In addition to the usual warnings about not subclassing things, `Deferred` is a *particularly* bad thing to subclass, because its behavior assumes very specific things about its own implementation, and will not react well to having certain methods overridden.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that video! It has totally changed the way I design code.

Comment: This answer is outdated as of 2019.

Use the official API:
https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.html#addTimeout

Answer (score 1):

We do it like this using a decorator. This method has the advantage that the deferred is cancelled when the timeout is reached. This should somehow become part of the Twisted library imho

```
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor

def timeout(secs):
    """Decorator to add timeout to Deferred calls"""
    def wrap(func):
        @defer.inlineCallbacks
        def _timeout(*args, **kwargs):
            raw_d = func(*args, **kwargs)
            if not isinstance(raw_d, defer.Deferred):
                defer.returnValue(raw_d)

            timeout_d = defer.Deferred()
            times_up = reactor.callLater(secs, timeout_d.callback, None)

            try:
                raw_result, timeout_result = yield defer.DeferredList(
                    [raw_d, timeout_d], fireOnOneCallback=True, fireOnOneErrback=True,
                    consumeErrors=True)
            except defer.FirstError as e:  # Only raw_d should raise an exception
                assert e.index == 0
                times_up.cancel()
                e.subFailure.raiseException()
            else:  # timeout
                if timeout_d.called:
                    raw_d.cancel()
                    raise Exception("%s secs have expired" % secs)

            # no timeout
            times_up.cancel()
            defer.returnValue(raw_result)
        return _timeout
return wrap
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, my answer is not about threads, but as it was said, you can implement timeout functionality as a separate helper:

```
from twisted.internet import defer

def add_watchdog(deferred, timeout=0.05):

    def callback(value):
        if not watchdog.called:
            watchdog.cancel()
        return value

    deferred.addBoth(callback)

    from twisted.internet import reactor
    watchdog = reactor.callLater(timeout, defer.timeout, deferred)

d = defer.Deferred()
add_watchdog(d)
```

Then you can trap `defer.TimeoutError` in deferred's errback if you need.

Comment: hmmm seems like cancellation is missing

Comment: @CarlD'Halluin , care to elaborate, or suggest an edit?